# Changing color themes in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to change the color of my Hello World app.

Right now it looks like this in the emulator (purple bar, pink floating icon):

[image]

But when I change the theme setting, I get a bunch of rendering errors (note that I tried to choose Material Light):

[image]

And when I try to run the app again it still looks purple/pink as it did in the first pic. I'm not really sure how to make heads or tails of these kinds of errors or how I am supposed to fix them.

Comment: It literally says what you have to do. "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat descendant with the design library"

Comment: I don't know what that means exactly. What's a Theme.AppCompat descendant? With what design library? What do either of those mean? How do I know where to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the theme of the *preview window*. This is used to view how your layout would look using a given theme. It does *not* change the theming on your phone when running your app—it is just a preview.

To actually change the colors you need to change the theme. Usually this would be the `AppTheme` that is referencing some colors.

Locate your `colors.xml` in `res/values/` and modify the colors there:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

These colors get used by the theme generated at project creation, looking like this in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

You could also remove the reference and edit the colors in the theme directly, but that is usually not the clean way. Your `styles.xml` would also be the right place to add more themes—which in turn you could preview in Android Studio.

Comment: I am a little confused. Are you suggesting that it is better practice to edit colors.xml, or styles.xml?

Comment: @DoubleBass Add and modify colors in `colors.xml` then reference them from `styles.xml`. Add / modify `styles.xml` to configure styles and themes

Comment: I am trying to understand when I'd change one from the other. Because let's say I previewed Material Light and liked it (or maybe I liked it but wanted a slightly darker grey or something). I would then change the one in styles.xml to style name = Material? And then parent would reference Material Light action bar somehow? And then does this somehow update colors.xml automatically depending on what I choose?

Comment: And how do I get the preview window to just mirror what the underlying code is showing? i.e. get the preview window to show what the emulator would show if you ran it

Comment: @DoubleBass leave your preview to use the AppTheme. Then just change the colors in colors.xml to e.g `#555555`. If you just change the name of the style it wont compile. Again, the preview has nothing to do with the actual code, you can preview available themes, not modify or apply them

Comment: So is this line in style.xml: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` something I should never edit?

Comment: @DoubleBass Since you seem to be a beginner, try getting familiar with the android framework first. You could e.g. remove the `DarkActionBar` part to get black text....

Comment: Getting familiar with the framework is exactly what I'm trying to do -- I don't understand how all this interlinks together. I can't tell which pieces I actually need to focus on editing. I'm assuming the SDK changer on the preview pane is also just a preview function as well and isn't changing the SDK version being used?

Comment: @DoubleBass so try things :) Yes. Preview is just preview. nothing else. here you can find full information on themes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Is there a better place than SO to ask noob Android questions? I often find the official docs hard to understand (or I end up having a bunch of questions)

Comment: @DoubleBass Many questions are already answered, and if not, people will be happy to help with all kinds of questions, as long as they show you made an effort and fit with the guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

[image] Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 or  Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

```
 1. color.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#1bade3</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#1bade3</color>
</resources>

 2. themes.xml file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.MsgShareApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```